# How to block all external (outside LAN) incoming connections on a PC

Tags: networking, firewall, windows-firewall, windows-home-server

As the title says.  I basically want to have a machine/server that can only be connected to from within the local network.

Is there a way that I can use Windows firewall to do this?  I am running windows home server 2011.

Comment: Your Internet-facing firewall should already be doing this. Do you have a reason to believe that's not the case?

Comment: I guess that's true.

Comment: Further, the default configuration of Windows Firewall is to block all inbound connections, so unless this has been changed on the device the only unsolicited traffic accepted by the server will be listed in the *Inbound Rules* section of WF

Comment: Probably want to ensure that things like UPnP etc are disabled.